# Question on operator of hilbert space, why $f(x)=\sum_{i}(f|e_i)e_i$?

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

let $(V,(. |.))$ a Hilbert space. Let $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^\infty $ an orthonormal basis and $f:V\to V$ a linear application. Here are my questions :

1) Why $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty (f,e_i)e_i$ ?

2) Why the space need to be Hilbert and not only prehilbertien ?

3) Why $Tr(f)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty (fe_i,e_i)$ ?

I'm new on the site, and a beginner in linear algebra over hilbert space. I hope you'll be able to answer my questions.

Best wishes.

Bob,

Comment: The formula $(f,e_i)$ makes no sense, $e_i$ is a vector of $V$ whereas $f$ is a linear map... You probably mean $(f(x),e_i)$.

Answer (score 2):

**1)** You know that $$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \lambda_ie_i$$
where $\lambda_i\in\mathbb R$. Now, since $\{e_i\}$ is an orthonormal basis, you'll get,
$$\left< f(x),e_i\right>=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \left<\lambda_j e_j,e_i\right>=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \lambda_j\underbrace{\left<e_j,e_i\right>}_{=\delta_{ij}}=\lambda_i.$$
Notice that $\left<f(x),e_i\right>e_i$ is the projection of $f(x)$ over $span(e_i)$.

**2)** The fact that $$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \lambda_ie_i$$
exist come from the convergence of the sum $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \lambda_i e_i.$$

Indeed, prove that $f_n(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i e_i$ is a cauchy sequence, you'll get the result.

**3)** I think you have all elements to answer.